# can't remove bike from ascent trainer

Tags: trainer

I've used the Ascent fluid trainer for a few years now. My bike is stuck on the trainer. I've applied WD-40. When I turn the adjustment knob, the rear wheel isn't being released. Any ideas? Please help!

Comment: A photo would really help.  Have you left it in the trainer for years and been riding vigorously?  Sounds like the clamps may have deformed around your rear skewer, especially if its not the one that came with the trainer.  Might need brute force.   Please post a photo.

Comment: Could the mechanism that releases the skewer be broke at the shaft so that the knob just spins perhaps? Otherwise I think Criggie may be on the right track. More info! :)